# Getting error org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException

Tags: hibernate, struts

I am using jasypt 1.9.0 using for db password encryption

## jdbc.properties

```
jdbc.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
jdbc.username=aosmaster
jdbc.password=ENC(aiQkX+5+EicZU3x0/ZWeW9ExV+OW/yc+)
```

## applicationcontext.xml

```
<bean class="org.jasypt.spring.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
                <property name="config">
                    <bean class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig">
                        <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES" />
                        <property name="passwordSysPropertyName" value="APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:/META-INF/props/db/jdbc.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I add into the JBOSS run.bat

```
rem JVM memory allocation pool parameters. Modify as appropriate.
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms128m -Xmx512m -DAPP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD=aiQkX+5+EicZU3x0/ZWeW9ExV+OW/yc+
```

I am getting error. I am unable to find out the solution for last 3 days please help me out

```
org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException
2012-05-19 09:49:01,562 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:981)
```

Finally I fixed this problem:

First we would need to decide on an encryption algorithm and a password. Then we would use the commandline tools that ship with Jasypt to encrypt our database password above:
c:\jasypt 9.0.1\bin  input="mypassword" algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES password=MY_APPS_PWD

kh1AU2abA4JpwlW1eqixhUzI0PerdI0Z

paste into jdbc property ENC(kh1AU2abA4JpwlW1eqixhUzI0PerdI0Z)

The important thing to take away from the above is the configuration. The property passwordSysPropertyName tells Jasypt that it should load the encryption password from a system property named APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD.
Now, as I described above, I add a runtime property to my container so that this password gets injected into the runtime environment as a system property:

I add into  run.bat into jboss

set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -DAPP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD=MY_APPS_PWD

the run.bat file.

Cheers!

Comment: It might be helpful if you could post your solution as an answer, and then accept it.